# Vertices not Showing up on Object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode, vertices

Hi so I just added a circle with vertices 32.
and when i go into edit mode they dont show up on the circle? I need to do some work with it and i need to see the vertices.
Any ideas why its not showing up? 
I have tried alt-H and that wont work.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Switch to vertex manipulation mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to Vertex manipulation mode. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: ughh i cant believe I missed that. thank you so much :)

Comment: that's ok. We all do that sometimes. I forget shortcuts I know very well more often than you'd think. I tried to find the W menu with Ctrl+W for a while once.